# EUnit and io:format

Tags: erlang

I want to test some third-party Erlang code using EUnit.

The output from the code's functions is displayed to the standard output using `io:format/2`. I would like to capture that output and perform an `?assert` test on the string that would be printed out. I cannot modify the third-party code.

Is the a way to do this with Erlang? (For instance, in Java I can simply use System.setOut() to an output stream).

**Update:**

The `group_leader/2` seems to be on the right track.

But, I still don't see how that allows me to capture the string printed by `io:format` so I can test my assertion. A very simplified example of the code is:

```
result(Value) ->
    io:format("Result: ~w~n", [Value]).

test_result() ->
    ?assertMatch("Result: 5~n", result(5)).
```

Clearly, the return from function `result/1` is the atom `ok`, but I actually want to test the string that was output to the console (i.e. `"Result: 5~n"`).

Am I wrong with this approach, because it seems nobody else does this (judging by my lack of search results)?

Background: the third-party code is an interactive console application, so all of the  functions just use `io:format` to show results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use dbg (the Erlang tracer) for this. You can trace the calls made to io:format/2 by a process and receive a trace message from it. You can use this trace message to assert that what is being used to call io:format/2,3 is correct. The benefit from this is that you don't have to interfere with EUnit since it already is capturing the actual IO messages.

A small example could be (adjust to your unit test[s]):

```
1> HandleFun = fun(Trace, Parent) -> Parent ! Trace, Parent end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.113037538>
2> dbg:tracer(process, {HandleFun, self()}).
{ok,<0.119.0>}
3> IOCallingFun = fun(F) -> 
3>   timer:sleep(5000),
3>   io:format("Random: ~p~n",[random:uniform(1000)]), 
3>   F(F) 
3> end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.13229925>
4> PidToTrace = erlang:spawn_link(fun() -> IOCallingFun(IOCallingFun) end).
<0.123.0>
Random: 93
Random: 444
5> dbg:p(PidToTrace, [c]).
{ok,[{matched,nonode@nohost,1}]}
6> dbg:tp(io, format, []).
{ok,[{matched,nonode@nohost,3}]}
Random: 724
Random: 946 
Random: 502 
7> flush().
Shell got {trace,<0.123.0>,call,{io,format,["Random: ~p~n",[724]]}}
Shell got {trace,<0.123.0>,call,{io,format,["Random: ~p~n",[946]]}}
Shell got {trace,<0.123.0>,call,{io,format,["Random: ~p~n",[502]]}}
ok
8> exit(PidToTrace).
** exception exit: <0.123.0>
9> dbg:stop_clear().
ok
10>
```

So in other words you simply start the trace before you start your unit test, test the trace messages and then kill the trace. **Make sure you only trace on the process making the calls!** otherwise you'll get messages from all over the place. You can see how the trace messages look like here: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#trace-3

Using this you can also test things like that the process takes the correct path (E.g. calls the right functions which you would expect) or sending correct messages to other processes etc. It is often overlooked in unit tests but it can be quite powerful. One point though is that it can *quickly* become over engineering, be careful.

This might not be the accepted answer but it is a good tool to use for testing sometimes :)

Good luck.

Comment: A very detailed response, I will need a little time to understand your suggestion. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**Approach 1: using meck**

This code, tested, should do exactly what you are asking for. It does some quite advanced meck tricks (especially when it calls `meck:passthrough/0`), but I think it is still very clear.

```
% UUT
foo() ->
    io:format("Look ma no newlines"),
    io:format("more ~w~n", [difficult]),
    io:format("~p dudes enter a bar~n", [3]),
    ok.

% Helper: return true if mock Mod:Fun returned Result at least once.
meck_returned(Mod, Fun, Result) ->
    meck_returned2(Mod, Fun, Result, meck:history(Mod)).

meck_returned2(_Mod, _Fun, _Result, _History = []) ->
    false;
meck_returned2(Mod, Fun, Result, _History = [H|T]) ->
    case H of
        {_CallerPid, {Mod, Fun, _Args}, MaybeResult} ->
            case lists:flatten(MaybeResult) of
                Result -> true;
                _      -> meck_returned2(Mod, Fun, Result, T)
            end;
        _ -> meck_returned2(Mod, Fun, Result, T)
    end.

simple_test() ->
    % Two concepts to understand:
    % 1. we cannot mock io, we have to mock io_lib
    % 2. in the expect, we use passthrough/0 to actually get the output
    %    we will be looking for in the history! :-)
    ok =  meck:new(io_lib, [unstick, passthrough]),
    meck:expect(io_lib, format, 2, meck:passthrough()),
    ?assertMatch(ok, foo()),
    %?debugFmt("history: ~p", [meck:history(io_lib)]),
    ?assert(meck_returned(io_lib, format, "Look ma no newlines")),
    ?assert(meck_returned(io_lib, format, "more difficult\n")),
    ?assert(meck_returned(io_lib, format, "3 dudes enter a bar\n")),
    ?assertNot(meck_returned(io_lib, format, "I didn't say this!")),
    ?assert(meck:validate(io_lib)).
```

**Approach 2: using mock_io**

More recently (May 2017) I wrote [mock_io](https://github.com/marco-m/mock_io), a very simple way to mock both input and output of the Unit Under Test, by implementing the Erlang I/O protocol.

With mock_io, the equivalent code becomes:

```
% UUT
foo() ->
    io:format("Look ma no newlines"),
    io:format("more ~w~n", [difficult]),
    io:format("~p dudes enter a bar~n", [3]),
    ok.

simple_test() ->
    Expected = <<"Look ma no newlines"
                 "more difficult\n",
                 "3 dudes enter a bar\n">>,
    {Pid, GL} = mock_io:setup(),
    ?assertMatch(ok, foo()),
    ?assertEqual(Expected, mock_io:extract(Pid)),
    mock_io:teardown({Pid, GL}).
```

Note also that mock_io allows to inject data in the UUT input channel, be it stdin or any other channel. For example:

```
% UUT
read_from_stdin() ->
    io:get_line("prompt").

% Test
inject_to_stdin_test() ->
    {IO, GL} = mock_io:setup(),
    mock_io:inject(IO, <<"pizza pazza puzza\n">>),
    ?assertEqual("pizza pazza puzza\n", uut:read_from_stdin()),
    ?assertEqual(<<>>, mock_io:remaining_input(IO)),
    mock_io:teardown({IO, GL}).
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at erlang:group_leader/2, using it you can set a new group leader which will capture the IO which is sent.

I know that eunit does this as well to capture output which is done in the test code so it might not play nice, you'll have to try it out and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

IO is in Erlang done by normal message passing (with some exception as raw mode of file) so you can put your own server in place of standard io server using `erlang:group_leader/2` call. Note that group leader is inherited by spawned processes so you can just set this group leader only for far predecessor of process you would like capture output from. Then you can do some tricky filtering or capturing in your fake io server which cen redirect traffic to original one.

For io server protocol see [Is there a specification of the group leader protocol that handles IO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283350/is-there-a-specification-of-the-group-leader-protocol-that-handles-io) and follow links mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

what about: io:format(user,"Result: ~w~n", [Value]) ?

Comment: As I explained, the io:format() calls are in third-party code that I cannot modify. So, I do not see how your suggestion helps in my particular case.

Comment: ok, I missed that part, sorry. However it is very strange system in that case. Console output was always considered as a side effect, which is not part of functionality. In that case I would overload/mock io module and capture console output.